# What are "Benson Chords"?

Tags: guitar, chords, jazz

George Benson was a jazz guitarist well before he became known as mainly an R&B vocalist and guitarist.   His guitar playing style incorporates distinctive chords sometimes called "Benson Chords" or "Benson Shapes"

What are the templates for Benson Shapes?

Comment: Hi,  please post the citatations for this chord name.  Are you sure that none of the biographical material explains what the chords are.

Comment: The presence of answers elsewhere (e.g., in bibliographic material) is not a reason to avoid posting a question here that hasn't yet been asked on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don Latarski, in his (highly recommended) book [Chord Embellishments for Guitar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004M17OJS) defines Benson Shapes as:

[image]

I don't even know Don Latarski but if you think this is useful, check out his other chord embellishments and support him.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the term "Benson chords" is actually used or refers to anything special (obviously, Benson didn't "invent" any new chords). I've found [one single reference](https://books.google.nl/books?id=nKR6zkBrGKQC&lpg=PA36&ots=yKKgf7yXqK&dq=%22benson%20shapes%22&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q=%22benson%20shapes%22&f=false) that refers to "Benson shapes", but that's just (minor or major) thirds with the highest note doubled one octave lower, so I wouldn't say they are anything special or anything that is very idiosyncratic to Benson's playing style. A citation where and in which context you found those terms would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My researching suggests

[minor 9th](https://www.fundamental-changes.com/play-guitar-like-george-benson-video-lesson/),   or a  [detailed book](https://www.sheetmusicplus.com/title/best-of-george-benson-sheet-music/3986126?ac=1&aff_id=61215) explaining his styles,

Comment: Comment would have been better, but I do realise that it's a google sort of question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/50479)

Comment: @Shevliaskovic that's why I physically typed "minor 9th"  there :-)